# route codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, shared-hosting

I have a problem with my routes file in codeigniter. On Wamp, my routes run correctly. But, on my server (shared hosting), my routes doesn't run.

My homepage is in fr folder. My Controller is Index. So my default controller is 'fr/index'.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'fr/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

When I write www.domainName.tld, I get "File not found." without css style. In source code I have

1 File not found. 
2

while when I write www.domainName.tld/aaaa (404 error), I have a really 404 error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>404 Page Not Found</title>
<style type="text/css">

::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 40px;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #003399;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
    padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
}

code {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    color: #002166;
    display: block;
    margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}

#container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
}

p {
    margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
        <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My .HTACCESS  run correctly :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#Sub-dir e.g: /cmsms
#RewriteBase /
#
# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
# Empêche la visualisation de l’arborescence, n’a rien à voir avec le masquage du « index.php ». Options -Indexes 
# Active le module de réécriture d’URL. RewriteEngine on 
# Toutes les URL qui ne correspondent pas à ces masques sont réécrites.
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets/|robots.txt) 
# Toutes les autres URL vont être redirigées vers le fichier index.php. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I think is a hosting problem because on wamp, my instruction run correctly but not on my server.

Have you an idea ?

Thank for your answers.

Comment: have you check `$config['base_url']` of your config file?

Comment: Yes. My base_url is empty. When I make a link, I used base_url (localhost) because my files structure is in server.

Comment: assign your server url to base_url and try again

Comment: I have the same problem. Now, when I try to access on my homepage, I have many links to 404 error. Always File not found for my homepage =/

Comment: what url you assign to base_url?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'centraledachatbellefrance.com';

Comment: first don't write the domain name. change it to example.com.  
second : try http://example.com/index.php
:)

Comment: Okok sorry. Always the same problem. I removed index.php to URL with HTACCESS file. no change with or without

Answer (score 0):

Which version of codeigniter are you running on?
If you are in v3 then check out your file name of controller and model ...if the starting letter of those files are not capital in letter then rename it 
The starting letter of model and controller filename must be in capital

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not in v3 but I try to change my default_controller to Welcome. I rename welcome.php to Welcome.php and class welcome extends CI_Controller to class Welcome extends CI_Controller.
I have the same problem. Just File not found.
In wamp, it's run correctly but not on my server. I don't understand why.

Comment: No. I have the same problem. Have you an idea ?

Comment: Can you show me your file structure ..so i would hVe better idea and also the config file base url n routes codes

Comment: It's impossible now but I show you my file structure to 3 hours. I'm sorry.

Comment: Have you got .htaccess on the folder of your site or not ??

Comment: Did you try renaming ur other file name like you did to welcome.php to Welcome.php ... The thing i just notice that you tried for only welcome.php...in codeigniter if your one file has name error then it will not load even if its a welcome.php is fyn ... So i think you rename all the files name to the capital letter starting n class name also begining with capital letter as u did for welcome ...and dont forget for model files also

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have the solution. It's a problem between htaccess et routes files. Remove your htaccess or edit it.